# Previous path tracking with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In this code both previousPath and the location are the same:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useMatches, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import './breadcrumbs.css';
import { NavigationContext } from '../../utils/NavigationProvider';

const BreadCrumbs = () => {
  const { previousPath, handleNavigation } = useContext(NavigationContext);
  const location = useLocation();
  let matches = useMatches();
  let crumbs = matches
    .filter((match) => Boolean(match.handle?.crumb))
    .map((match) => match.handle.crumb(match.data));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname !== previousPath) {
      handleNavigation(location);
    }
  }, [location.pathname]);

  console.log(location.pathname);
  console.info(previousPath);

  const formatPreviousPath = (previousPath) => {
    const formattedPath = previousPath.replace(/-|\//g, ' ').toUpperCase();
    return formattedPath;
  }

  return (
    <div className='breadcrumbs'>
      <div className='breadcrumbs__container'>
        <span>{crumbs[0].props.children.toUpperCase()}</span>
        <div className='breadcrumbs__path'>
          <span>{formatPreviousPath(previousPath)}</span>
          <p>/</p>
          <span>{location.pathname.replace(/-|\//g, ' ').toUpperCase()}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BreadCrumbs;
```

But I want the previousPath to have the path from previous location. Here is the code for Context provider:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';

export const NavigationContext = createContext();

export const NavigationProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [previousPath, setPreviousPath] = useState('/');

  const handleNavigation = (location) => {
    setPreviousPath(location.pathname);
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContext.Provider value={{ previousPath, handleNavigation }}>
      {children}
    </NavigationContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I tried introducing one more state in my Context called currentPath and I would update it location of the current page where the breadcrumb is, but it doesn't update the state. Where am I wrong with this?

To add more context: I just want to display the name of the previous page dynamically. **Don't need to navigate to it.**

Comment: I'm not an avid user of React hooks, but I notice that `createContext()`, a react class, is passed to provide context fro `react-dom-router`. Are you sure that is as intended?

Comment: @paddotk There are hooks for navigation purposes but no hooks regards to getting the path of the previous page. I want for the previous path to be accessible, no matter the page where the user finds himself/herself.

Comment: You seem to be overcomplicating things. See the official docs for a [breadcrumbs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-matches#breadcrumbs) example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useNavigate hook to navigate previous page.

```
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
```

inside your component:

```
const navigate = useNavigate()
```

and put the function that you want to use, example:

```
<button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>Back</button>
```